# Which pattern could I use for a game with complex rules?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm creating a 2D turn-based multiplayer (no AI) board game in Java using the **MVC** pattern in which there are a lot of rules and conditions, I can't figure out a good pattern to implement them, for example:

- The player can choose a character from a pool of 12: They have similarities between them but each character could move differently, could use different items, etc.
- The movement ability, which could already be different based on the character, could change during the game by using items (for just one turn) or after some events (for all the game). *For example moving by 3 cells instead of 2.*

All these rules could be different based on the selected game-mode which could also change the winning conditions and some game strategies.

Which **patterns** could be suitable for this? Especially the fact that different characters could have **different behaviors** depending also on the **gamemode** and the **state** of the game.

*I know there are already a lot of questions on game patterns on SO but I could not find something suitable to this.*

Comment: Though the question is well formulated, it looks like you are asking someone to design your entire application for you. Forget design patterns for now. Can you come up with an initial set of classes and components for your game and post them as part of your question? The idea is to evolve your design in steps instead of a big bang approach..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will edit my question as soon as possible with the UML diagrams I'm working on.

Comment: No problem. Chances are that you won't need to come back here for an answer once you come up with an initial design. I have posted an answer to help you with the thought process of it rather than providing the entire solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to design this game, I would try to identify different objects that are hidden in the problem statement as follows :

> The player can choose a character from a pool of 12

Hmmm. So I am going to need a `Player` and `Character` class.

> They have similarities between them but each character could move
>   differently, could use different items

Ok. So there is behavior that is common to each `Character` but Characters can also have additional behavior that is different from the common behavior. Let's add methods in Character for each behavior that is common across characters.

But what about the behavior that is only applicable for a particular type of Character? Ok so I definitely need a way to add behavior to my characters at runtime.

Hmmmm. Let's create an `interface` called `Behavior` which contains a method called.. umm.. behave. Let's create a couple of classes that implement this interface and implement the behave method.

So far so good. We have a `Character` class that can be used to instantiate one of 12 characters. We have a `Behavior` hierarchy for additional behaviors not common across characters. We now need to make these two classes work together in such a way that we can add behavior at runtime. Throughout my career, I have been told to favor composition over inheritance. So I guess I am going to make character `have-a` `Behavior` by adding a `Behavior` reference in `Character`. There is a name for this pattern.. this is the `Strategy` pattern.

The most important take-away from the above explanation is that you don't look at a problem and say `what design pattern can I apply?`. Instead, you come up with an initial draft of what your design will be like and say `this looks like the XYZ pattern`

There are lot of requirements that I have not covered in this answer. The idea of this answer is to explain to you the kind of thought process you can put in to come up with an initial draft of your design and keep evolving it rather than over-designing right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ECS (entity component system) architectural pattern and DDD methodology. DDD was created specifically for application with complex domain logic and games usually has it.

Some useful links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

To fully understand DDD you HAVE TO read Eric Evans book called Domain Driven Design.

Comment: I was talking about exactly this in my answer. Evolving design through iterations by identifying different objects (a.k.a domains)

Comment: yes, I read Your answer. I just think that pointing to DDD is a good road sign for that problem, since you can't possibly explain everything in one SO answer.

Comment: I agree . Although, I believe that there is no need to read a book on domain driven design to know how to apply it. If one is willing to accept that their design will evolve over time and ready to take an iterative approach to building an application, everything else like design patterns and DDD will be secondary. Doing is more important than knowing..